# NextJS and Storybook build `index.html` - how to serve Storybook as part of the same domain?

Tags: reactjs, next.js, storybook

Is there a way to `serve`  the static `index.html` that is generated when we build storybook from nextJS?

My static Storybook site is built to `~/build/storybook/...`.

And I want to be able to use NextJS to route to that file e.g.

`http://mysite/storybook`

How would you do this with NextJS file based router?